# How can i put my form value in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms

I want to make a script where i can put my form in the javascript array `invoer[]` and display the total

It constantly stops working and i searched a lot, i really can't find the right way :D

This is my javascript code

```
var strijk = ['broek', 'hemd', 'tshirt', 'lakens', 'korte broek', 'babykledij'];
var minuten = [5, 10, 5, 6, 3, 3];

function invoerstrijk() {
    document.write("<form action='' method='get' name='strijkform'>");
    for (var a = 0; a < minuten.length; a++) {
        document.write(strijk[a] + "<input id='" + strijk[a] + "' name ='" + strijk[a] + "' type='text' />" + "<BR>");
    }

    document.write("<button onclick='opgeven()'>opgeven</button>");
    document.write("</form>");
}

function opgeven() {
    var invoer = [];
    for (var a = 0; a < minuten.length; a++) {
        invoer[a] = document.getElementByI(strijk[a]).value;
    }

    var totaal;
    for (var a = 0; a < minuten.length; a++) {
        totaal += parseint(invoer[a]) * parseint(minuten[a]);
    }
    document.write("<input name=" + strijk[a] + " type='text' value=" + invoer[a] + " readonly />");
    if (invoer != []) {
        document.write("totaal aantal minuten" + totaal);
    } else {
        document.write("geen invoer");
    }
}
```

my html looks likes this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" >
//my javasccript
</script>

<button id="B1" onclick="invoerstrijk()" >Nieuwe strijk</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should read a good JavaScript book, if you are serious about programming web stuff.

Comment: Avoid using `document.write`

Comment: it's for school, i'm learning it. I know some but not that much, you are all helping me! ty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
var strijk = ['broek', 'hemd', 'tshirt', 'lakens', 'korte broek', 'babykledij'];
var minuten = [5, 10, 5, 6, 3, 3];

function invoerstrijk() {
  document.write("<form action='' method='get' name='strijkform' onsubmit='return false;'>");
  for (var a = 0; a < minuten.length; a++) {
    document.write(strijk[a] + "<input id='" + strijk[a] + "' name ='" + strijk[a] + "' type='text' />" + "<BR>");
  }

  document.write("<button onclick='opgeven()'>opgeven</button>");
  document.write("</form>");
}

function opgeven() {
  var invoer = [];
  for (var a = 0; a < minuten.length; a++) {
    invoer.push(document.getElementById(strijk[a]).value);
  }

  var totaal = 0;
  for (var a = 0; a < minuten.length; a++) {
    totaal += (parseInt(invoer[a]) * parseInt(minuten[a]));
  }
  // !!! this is wrong because it is out of for !!!
  //document.write("<input name=" + strijk[a] + " type='text' value=" + invoer[a] + " readonly />");
  if (invoer.length > 0) {
    document.write("totaal aantal minuten " + totaal);
  } else {
    document.write("geen invoer");
  }
}
```

Some explanation:

1. *onsubmit='return false;'* - to not send form and reload page.
2. *invoer.push(document.getElementById(strijk[a]).value);* - to put elements into array use push.
3. *var totaal = 0;* - init variable 0 bacause it is undefined.
4. Misspellings: Bad: *parseint*, Good: *parseInt*; Bad: *getElementByI*, Good: *getElementById*
5. The line with readonly input is wrong because it is out of for so *a* variable is not defined.

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/mgkm3b?p=preview)